# The requested URL /node was not found on this server

Tags: 7, uri

I am setting up Drupal locally in my Ubuntu. 
I used drush to download and install Drupal 7. (using mysqladmin to create the database and the user)

All worked well, I have the default homepage, but when I try to do any action (logging in, registering) I get a 404. I imagine the mod_rewrite doesn't work..

I installed the Apache module and enabled it, restarted the server, but no lack...

I am guessing mod_rewrite needs more parameterization...?

update: I can access correctly the page with this url:

```
http://localhost/index.php?q=user
```

so I guess my mod_rewrite clearly doesn't work as it should..

Comment: Do you have `AllowOverride None` in your httpd.conf or vhost file for that site's web root? If so try changing that to `AllowOverride All` and restarting Apache

Comment: hm, my /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file is empty.. it's there, but it's empty.

Comment: What about in sites-enabled/default (or something similar) that'll be the default vhost file on Ubuntu I think

Comment: it was already set to AllowOverride All ... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized I had not restarted apache2 service after enabling mod_rewrite... It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Have you verified that the .htaccess file from the Drupal 7 core package is in the website root?

You can easily download and extract that file from drupal.org base package:  http://drupal.org/project/drupal

Comment: the .htaccess file is in the website root. (I think as I used drush to deploy, everything was done as it should from the Drupal perspective..) it's mostly something with Apache

Comment: I had copied the site over and somehow the hidden files (.htaccess) did not get copied over. I looked all over for an answer - Thanks!!